# Predicting next value of game results

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am working on predicting game output. The game has three seats. **Seat A** , **seat B** and **seat C**. Each time only one seat will win randomly.

I have written LSTM code to predict the next value. I made the dataset of around 8000 games and recorded the results. But LSTM is not predicting the next value. It is either predicting either all "0"s or all "1"s. I'm curious why it is not learning.

- here you can find [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WZBMYO-Oi3uErPlBXphXFAACmn9VK_yZ/view?usp=sharing)
- here is attached my google colab [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xDzrfbTu-OXSdNRcbL7B_Qb94hlKNa5i)

```
# univariate data preparation
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd
# split a univariate sequence into samples
df = pd.read_csv('DatasetLarge.csv') # here you can find dataset https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WZBMYO-Oi3uErPlBXphXFAACmn9VK_yZ
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
# Removing some errors of dataset
df=df.replace(to_replace ="q", 
                 value ="a")
df=df.replace(to_replace ="aa", 
                 value ="a")
df=df.replace(to_replace ="cc", 
                 value ="c")
#label encoding
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.values)
df=le.transform(df)
# define input sequence
raw_seq=df
# choose a number of time steps
n_steps = 5
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(raw_seq, n_steps)
# summarize the data
for i in range(len(X)):
    print(X[i], y[i])

#Spliting dataset for train and test
X_train=X[0:7500]
y_train=y[0:7500]
X_test=X[7500:]
y_test=y[7500:]

import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten,Input,LSTM
n_features = 1
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], n_features))
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='softmax', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
# # fit model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)
# # demonstrate prediction
X_test=X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], n_features))
yhat_classes =(model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")

print(yhat_classes)
```

Please help me why it is not predicting correctly.

Comment: If "*Each time only one seat will win **randomly***", as you claim, then there is really nothing to be predicted here.

Comment: like @desernaut mentioned, you try to predict the randomness which does not make sense.

Comment: but I've used naive bayes for same problem, it is predicting with the accuracy of 38 to 42%. my concern is why the LSTM is not predicting even a single value after training